# In Vuejs how do I bind select options to object

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to use interpolation in a template select options like normal

```
<select class="form-control" id="staff" name="staff">
     <option selected disabled>- Select -</option>
  @foreach($staff as $aStaff)
     <option value="{{$aStaff->id}}">{{$aStaff->initials}}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

The compile error is clear

```
 Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead.
```

But i'm still unsure of correct usage.  Vue documentation simply gives example

```
<select v-model="selected">
 <!-- inline object literal -->
 <option v-bind:value="{ number: 123 }">123</option>
</select>
```

However i'm unsure how to translate this into using the foreach I need above

Something like this is invalid

```
<option :value="$aStaff->id">{{$aStaff->initials}}</option>
```

So just not sure how to interpret ?

Edit: tried using v-for, i get no errors but nothing in the select options

```
<select class="form-control" id="staff" name="staff">
    <option selected disabled>- Select -</option>
    <div v-for="aStaff in staff">
       <option :value="aStaff.id">aStaff.initials</option>
    </div>
 </select>
```

I have staff defined in custom component:

```
<sale v-if="showModal" @sale="calcFees" :staff="{{$staff}}"></sale>
```

So when i simply do `{{staff}}` in the component page, it shows the data i expect to see.

Sale.vue component definition:

```
<script>
  export default {
     data: function () {
       return {
       price: null
    }
   },
   props: {
    staff: {
        type: Array,
        required: true
    }
   },
   methods: {
      onSale(){
         this.$emit('sale', this.price) 
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Something is not working correctly. Your interpolated values are *server side* interpolations. Vue should never see them.

Comment: hi again :) yeh i realised i was using the wrong interpolations so i edited above with v-for instead but still not right - i can see the staff object correctly on the page but not in the select

Comment: What's in 'staff'? Where is it defined?

Comment: Did you add staff as a property in sale.vue?

Comment: yes forgot that too :) edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is iterating over a `div`. Instead, iterate the option.

```
<option v-for="aStaff in staff" :value="aStaff.id">{{aStaff.initials}}</option>
```

And remove the `div` of course.

Comment: thats great - i now have 3 options but getting the literal string "aStaff.initials" in the options instead of the value ?

Comment: @yoyoma Derp. Updated.